# como saber se console.log no JS tá retonando um dado sensível, ou é um console.log desnecessário?

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde a todos.

Sou totalmente iniciante em programação, e estou com atividade para realizar que devo conferir os arquivos do JS, e verificar se tem console.log, e caso tenha, devo verificar se é para um dado "sensível", ou se é desnecessário ter.

Devo checar todos os arquivos com essas duas situações, e pontuá-los para meu mentor.

Meu problema é que, não sei identificar quando se trata de dado sensível ou desnecessário.
Alguém pode me ajudar a tentar entender?

Obrigada.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Considerando que a aplicação está finalizada e/ou "em produção", teoricamente não deve haver nada sendo logado no console. Então você pode considerar que todos os console.log são desnecessários. Se são dados sensíveis, depende do que for considerado sensível por vocês... E se tiver dado sensível sendo exposto por console.log, o buraco é mais embaixo – dados sensíveis não deveriam estar presentes em nenhum lugar do javascript, ou estarão necessariamente expostos. Isso inclui o código-fonte e a memória (por exemplo, um dado sensível recebido de um servidor e armazenado em variável js).

Answer (score -1):

Ola. Eu entendo que sua preocupação por seguranca é bem valida e legitma.

Conceitualmente, o console. log é uma função que imprime um texto no console (no caso do JavaScript será possível visualizar através da ferramenta do desenvolvedor). Você utilizará esta função para te auxiliar no desenvolvimento, exibindo valores de variáveis em determinado ponto do código por exemplo (em tempo de execução).

Na pratica, o console é utilizado como uma especie de debug da aplicacao para validar se chegou aonde queria por exemplo.

Assim que eu termino o que tenho que fazer, eu costumo tirar todos os consoles da tela.

Comment: O console.log é tipo um "system.debug"?

Comment: Ele não chega exatamente ser um system.debug, mas ajuda muito na orientação se o sistema está comportando na forma que espera, entrando no bloco que vc quer, com o valor que vc quer.